# sumar cuantos objetos son iguales en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, javascript-objeto

> Estoy intentando sumar todos los objetos que son iguales y agregar las suma al final, por ejemplo el arreglo es así

```
data = [
  { from: '[None]', to: '[None]' },
  { from: '[None]', to: '[None]' },
  { from: '[None]', to: '[None]' },
  { from: '/default', to: '/default' },
  { from: '/default', to: '/default' },
  { from: '/default', to: '/default' },
  { from: '[None]', to: '/default' },
  { from: '[None]', to: '/default' },
  { from: 'Andres', to: '/default' },
];
```

> Y tiene que quedar asi

```
{ from: '[None]', to: '[None]', value: 3 },
{ from: '/default', to: '/default', value: 3 },
{ from: '[None]', to: '/default', value: 2 },
{ from: 'Andres', to: '/default' value: 1 },
```

Comment: donde esta el codigo js que muestra que lo intentaste??

Comment: Has intentado algo? O quieres que alguien te haga la tarea? Edita tu pregunta y añade el código de lo que has intentado, y los errores que te da

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { from: '[None]', to: '[None]' },
  { from: '[None]', to: '[None]' },
  { from: '[None]', to: '[None]' },
  { from: '/default', to: '/default' },
  { from: '/default', to: '/default' },
  { from: '/default', to: '/default' },
  { from: '[None]', to: '/default' },
  { from: '[None]', to: '/default' },
  { from: 'Andres', to: '/default' },
];

let res = [];

//Recorremos el arreglo...
data.forEach(item => {
  //Si el elemento no esta en res...
  if (res.findIndex(e => e.from === item.from && e.to === item.to) === -1){
    //Le agregamos la propiedad value con la cantidad de elementos iguales en data
    //Y lo agregamos a res
    res.push({
      ...item,
      value: data.filter(e => e.from === item.from && e.to === item.to).length
    });
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: El código se podría optimizar un poco más, usando un `for` en vez de `forEach` para poder saltearse los elementos repetidos pero eso ya depende del tamaño de `data`

Comment: ya lo resolví, y así lo resolví